# property of supremum

Tags: real-analysis

It seems that the following is the basic property of the supremum of a function:
$$\sup_{x \in I}f(x) - \inf_{y \in I}f(y) \geq \sup_{x, y \in I}f(x) - f(y)$$
I think This property is so obvious that the textbook just uses this without mentioning why.

But I want to know if this can be proven mathematically? I tried but it is not that straight forward to me. Can someone explain? Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inequality holds because the two things are equal.

To find $\sup_{x, y \in I}f(x) - f(y)$ you would find values of $x\in I$ which maximise $f$ and values of  $y\in I$ which minimise $f(y)$

In other words you set $x$ to be the supremum of $f$ over $I$ and $y$ to be the infimum of $f$ over $I$ and the subtract the two, which is precisely 
 $\sup_{x \in I}f(x) - \inf_{y \in I}f(y) $